# Firebase Google Sign In Implementation

Tags: android, google-api, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm a bit confused about what I'm passing through authWithOAuthToken for  parameter.

Does it mean the web application token provided by google developer console or the Android one?

Ex code:

```
if(googleSignInResult.isSuccess()){
        Log.d(TAG,"Google Login Successful");
        GoogleSignInAccount account = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();
        final String idToken = account.getIdToken();
        final String name = account.getDisplayName();
        final String email = account.getEmail();
        root.authWithOAuthToken("google", Constants.GOOGLE_OAUTH_KEY, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
               //Authenticated


            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG,firebaseError.getDetails());
            }
        });
```

Constants.GOOGLE_OAUTH_KEY is the key client id provided by Google developer console.
Whenever I try to sign in with google I enter onAuthenticationError and {"providerErrorInfo":{}} is printed to log.
Is there something I need to do to get the correct OAuth Token?

Comment: Wiring up Google authentication to Firebaseon Android is non-trivial, since you'll first need to authenticate the user with Google and then pass that information on to Firebase. You'll need some variation of the code in [the FirebaseUI library](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/google). Alternatively, you can just *use* FirebaseUI: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#using-firebaseui-for-authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth Key that you have to pass is not the key client id provided by GoogleDeveloperConsole.

To retrive that key you have to ask runtime for it.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-login-demo-android) to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

Download the source code from here ([Firebase Google Login Android](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/04/03/firebase-google-login-android/)). In this tutorial I have also shared the screenshots.

**Add these dependencies:**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/iv_image"
            android:src="@drawable/profileimage"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000"></View>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Email"
                android:id="@+id/tv_email"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#000000"></View>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#E02F2F"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/iv_google"
            android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tv_google"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Sign in with Google"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.deepshikha.googlepluslogin;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    ImageView iv_google;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ImageView iv_image;

    boolean boolean_google;
    TextView tv_name, tv_email, tv_google;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        listener();

    }

    private void init() {

        tv_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        tv_google = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_google);
        iv_google = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_google);
        iv_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_image);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d("LoginActivity", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d("LoginActivity", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(user);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        };


        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(MainActivity.this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }

    private void listener() {
        iv_google.setOnClickListener(this);
        tv_google.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.iv_google:
                break;
            case R.id.tv_google:
                if (boolean_google){
                    signOut();
                    tv_name.setText("");
                    tv_email.setText("");
                    boolean_google=false;
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(R.drawable.profileimage).into(iv_image);
                }else {
                    signIn();
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(null);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        }

    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("LoginActivity", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        try {

            dialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("LoginActivity", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("LoginActivity", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]

                        try {

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void signOut() {
        // Firebase sign out
        try {
            mAuth.signOut();

            // Google sign out
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        try {
            dialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        if (user != null) {
            String str_emailgoogle = user.getEmail();
            Log.e("Email", str_emailgoogle);
            tv_email.setText(str_emailgoogle);
            tv_name.setText(user.getDisplayName());
            boolean_google=true;
            tv_google.setText("Sign out from Google");

            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load( user.getPhotoUrl()).into(iv_image);


            Log.e("Profile", user.getPhotoUrl() + "");

        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d("LoginActivity", "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is requestIdToken ? and where to get it ? I'm bit confused

Answer (score 0):

I dont what methods are people using. And they dont seem to work for me. What works for me smoothly is the below code:

```js
startActivityForResult(
  AuthUI.getInstance()
  .createSignInIntentBuilder()
  .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
  .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build()))
  .build(),
  123
);
```

This is going to create a new activity and it will automatically generate Sign in Buttons for you. You dont need to write any code in your `xml file`.